# Get VS Test Explorer to show only test name not full type name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

My VS test explorer shows tests including the full type name, like so:

> CompanyName.ProjectName.Web.Tests.SutDoesWhatItShould

Instead of just:

> SutDoesWhatItShould

This is highly unreadable/annoying. How do I fix this?

I'm using the xunit runner for visual studio (prerelease) and xunit.net.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In v2 this is now configurable, see https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files

So you need to add to app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.methodDisplay" value="method"/>
</appSettings>
```

and as noted in the comments, you might need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Worked perfectly, but for others I found I needed to restart Visual Studio to see the change. At least on VS 2013.

Comment: @JamesHolland I had to restart VS 2015 also.

Comment: Vs2017 also needed to restart, but it worked like a charm

Comment: For me, normal tests are showing the method name, but tests with multiple TestCase() are showing the fully qualified namespace and name. This solution did not fix that (even after restarting VS).

Comment: Docs moved to https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files

Answer (score 8):

For **.NET Core** projects (with `.json` configuration):

1. Add `xunit.runner.json` file to your **test project** with following contents:

   `{
   "methodDisplay": "method"
   }`
2. Set `Copy if newer` from options for `xunit.runner.json` file you've just added
3. Build the test project

For more information refer to the [documentation](http://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html).